# how to take null values be the first from parseQuery (descending order)?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Let me explain.

Parse 1.5:


when I used a parseQuery and added a orderByDescending("createdAt"), the null values came first.

Parse 1.9:


now I have a problem, when I do this same query the null values come at the end.

The problem is that I retrieve the object from query using getFirstInBackground() method...

OBS.: I need to take these objects with null values at createdAt column because they were not been saved at the server yet, but I must show to the users the local objects if they don´t have got internet for a moment.

I could use 2 queries, one for search null values, and if it returns nothing, other query for 'normal' search. But, of course, this is not a good solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this related to the local Datastore being enabled ??

Comment: Yes, it´s enabled. Every query is made with localDatastore.

Comment: Do you use `fromLocalDatastore()` on your queries ?

Comment: Yes, all of them. The app has an activity that syncs from/to parse. After syncing, the user uses only localDatastore.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think there is way around it as the behaviour changed. Just use two separate queries